# .concat cannot read space

Tags: java, android, linux

i have a problem in this code

```
public void setTmbhUserFtp(View v) {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        Server server = serverlist.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() - 1);
        EditText EditAdduser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditAdduser);
        EditText EditPassworduser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditPassworduser);
        String sTextAdduser = EditAdduser.getText().toString();
        String sTextPassworduser = EditPassworduser.getText().toString();

        if (server != null && sTextAdduser.length() > 0
            && sTextPassworduser.length() > 0) {
        final String ADDUSER = "sh /home/add_user.sh".concat(sTextAdduser) .concat(sTextPassworduser);
        FtpConnect u = new FtpConnect();
        Command o = new Command(getResources().getText(R.string.adduser)
                .toString(), ADDUSER, server);
        u.setCommand(ADDUSER);

        pd = ProgressDialog.show(actual,
                getResources().getString(R.string.PleaseWait), o.getName());
        actualThreadCommand = o;
        Thread thread = new Thread(actual);
        thread.start();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                getResources().getText(R.string.gagal), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}
```

that code is using for excute in linux like this

```
sh /home/add_user.sh username password
```

but when i try from my android the username and password is being one

so the code is like this

```
sh /home/add_user.sh usernamepassword
```

if username is irfan and password is irfan, the code is detect

```
sh /home/add_user.sh irfanirfan
```

so username being irfanirfan and dont have a password

the code add_user.sh is

```
useradd $1; echo -e "$2\n$2" | passwd $1
```

how to resolving

```
final String ADDUSER = "sh /home/add_user.sh ".concat(sTextAdduser) .concat(sTextPassworduser);
```

after .concat(sTextAdduser) must be space

so in linux will excute

```
sh /home/add_user.sh irfan irfan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you may solve your problem:

```
final String ADDUSER = "sh /home/add_user.sh "+sTextAdduser+" "+sTextPassworduser;
```

Comment: This way we can give space in any String..Please try to print it Or try to Toast it if you have any doubt that you don't get the space..I have checked myself...by the way..what's the Error you are getting??

Answer (score 0):

```
final String ADDUSER = "sh /home/add_user.sh ".concat(sTextAdduser)
.concat(" ")
.concat(sTextPassworduser);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final String ADDUSER = "sh /home/add_user.sh "+sTextAdduser+"\\ "+sTextPassworduser;
```

use backSlash followed by a space to addSpace in any path in linux.